# ReactJS MUI Autocomplete with image

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI Autocomplete box which I want to render images next to options. I receive the images from request and they are byte[].

This is my code:

```
<Autocomplete
             disablePortal
             getOptionLabel={(option) => option.accountType || "Type"}
             id="combo-box-demo"
             options={accountTypes}
             sx={{width: 223, marginBottom: 1.25,
                  '.css-wb57ya-MuiFormControl-root-MuiTextField-root': {
                   width: '77%'}}}
             onChange={setAccountTypeForAdd}
             renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={accountTypeNameForEdit} />}/>
```

Here I get the accountTypes:

```
const getAllAccountTypes = async () => {
    const request = await requester(urls.accountTypes, methods.get);
    const response = await request.json();
    setAccountTypes(response);
};
```

Comment: Do you need like this https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#country-select

Comment: There is renderOption props in AutoComplete that you can use

Comment: There is any way to show image in the Textfield?